# A simple innerJoin Doctrine Query

Tags: doctrine, dql

I tried to generate a simple SQL select:

```sql
SELECT c.com_id, c.pro_id, c.com_nombre 
FROM bd_fn.fn_comuna c  
inner join bd_fn.fn_provincia p 
on (c.pro_id = p.pro_id) 
where p.pro_nombre = 'namepro';
```

But the DQL throw this error:

> Doctrine_Table_Exception' with message 'Unknown relation alias fn_provincia.

The doctrine version is 1.XX, the persistence was create by Visual Paradigm.
The DQL is this:

```php
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('c.com_id')
    ->from('fn_comuna c')
    ->innerJoin('c.fn_provincia p')
    ->where('p.pro_nombre=?',$namepro);
```

the class fn_comuna.php

```php
<?php
/**
 * "Visual Paradigm: DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE!"
 * 
 * This is an automatic generated file. It will be regenerated every time 
 * you generate persistence class.
 * 
 * Modifying its content may cause the program not work, or your work may lost.
 */

class Fn_comuna extends Doctrine_Record {
  public function setTableDefinition() {
    $this->setTableName('bd_fn.fn_comuna');
    $this->hasColumn('com_id', 'integer', 4, array(
        'type' => 'integer',
        'length' => 4,
        'unsigned' => false,
        'notnull' => true,
        'primary' => true, 
        'autoincrement' => false,
      )
    );
    $this->hasColumn('pro_id', 'integer', 4, array(
        'type' => 'integer',
        'length' => 4,
        'unsigned' => false,
        'notnull' => true,
      )
    );
    $this->hasColumn('com_nombre', 'string', 100, array(
        'type' => 'string',
        'length' => 100,
        'fixed' => false,
        'notnull' => true,
      )
    );
  }

  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->hasOne('Fn_provincia as pro', array(
        'local' => 'pro_id', 
        'foreign' => 'pro_id'
      )
    );
    $this->hasMany('Fn_institucion as fn_institucion', array(
        'local' => 'com_id', 
        'foreign' => 'com_id'
      )
    );
    $this->hasMany('Fn_replegal as fn_replegal', array(
        'local' => 'com_id', 
        'foreign' => 'com_id'
      )
    );
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: What is your doctrine schema?

Comment: Is the same as data base? bd_fn is the sql schema. I generated the persitence with ORM by Visual Paradigm, with Doctrine 1.xx, for a postgres data base. The Join is the problem. I do not know why, if the tables are related.

Comment: What's inside your doctrine model class `fn_comuna`?

Comment: you need to put the class generated by the ORM???

Comment: Yes of course. We will be able to see what Doctrine knows about your schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from your model class, the relation between `fn_comuna` & `fn_provincia` is called `pro`.

```php
$this->hasOne('Fn_provincia as pro', array(
    'local' => 'pro_id', 
    'foreign' => 'pro_id'
  )
);
```

So you have to use this name when you deal with join:

```php
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('c.com_id')
    ->from('fn_comuna c')
    ->innerJoin('c.pro p')
    ->where('p.pro_nombre=?', $namepro);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
p.pro_id = (SELECT p2.pro_id FROM etc..
```

To:

```
p.pro_id IN(SELECT p2.pro_id FROM etc..
```

Not sure why you need the subquery in the first place, why not just loose it and replace it with:

```
where pro_nombre = 'namepro'
```

Comment: Still not working. Yes the subquery is unuseful, thank. The problem is the join.

Comment: My solution to strange error the INNERJOIN


    ->select('c.com_id')
    ->from('fn_comuna c')
    //->innerJoin('c.fn_provincia p')
    ->where('c.pro_id = (SELECT p2.pro_id FROM fn_provincia p2 WHERE p2.pro_nombre = ?)',$proname);

thank anyway